# System Tray Not Opening After Windows 11 Update

Tags: windows-11, notification-area, bug

I recently installed the latest Windows update on my computer, and since then, I've been unable to open the system tray. Usually, I would just click on the system tray icon in the taskbar, but when I do that now, a dotted line appears:

[image]

It's quite frustrating because I rely on the system tray to access various important functions (wifi, brightness, sound volume, etc.). I'm not sure what exactly went wrong or how to fix it. I've tried restarting my computer, but that didn't resolve the issue. I've also checked for any pending updates or notifications, but everything seems up to date.

Here are the currently installed updates as shown by the Control Panel:

[image]

If the issue can't be resolved without uninstalling update(s), which one(s) should I uninstall?

Comment: Which system tray icon? Do you mean the up-arrow?

Comment: The rectangle containing LAN, sound, and battery icons shown in image 1

Comment: So you mean any one icon. Try to reboot the computer a couple of times, and if it persists then try it while booting from Safe mode.

Comment: Booted into safe mode. it doesn't open there either.

Comment: Very strange. Perhaps the answer below will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Windows 11 problem in general. 3 Windows 11 Pro machines here.

Try repairing Windows 11.

**1. DISM / SFC**  (50% success)

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

DISM and SFC are initial repairs. If that does not resolve the issue, run a Windows 11 Repair Install.

**2. Windows 11 Repair Install.**  (80%+ success)

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

```
Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download. 

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.

Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.  
Proceed normally answering the prompts. 

The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.
```

**3. Reinstall Windows 11.** (99% success)

If Repair Install and Keep Everything fails, the OS damage is more serious and / or the Windows User Profile is damaged.

In either case, back up all your data and do a fresh install of Windows 11.

Comment: Restarted. The problem persists :(

Comment: Try the Repair Install and see if that works. Much higher chance this will fix the issue.

Comment: There are 3 download buttons:
1.Windows 11 Installation Assistant 
2.Create Windows 11 Installation Media 
3.Download Windows 11 Disk Image (ISO) for x64 devices. 
Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Button number 2.  Download, create a USB Key. Then run Setup on the USB Key to start the repair install

Comment: I'm going to try to uninstall update files and see if that fixes the problem because I had no problem prior to the update.

Comment: Windows 11 updates are not causing issues here. That is why I suggested Repair.

Comment: Please remember that Windows updates  will reinstall every Patch Tuesday (monthly)

Comment: 2. "Windows 11 Repair Install" worked for me

Comment: Great - glad to here that